# Cannot build a Hudson plugin using Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-plugin, hudson-plugins

I cannot manage to build the Hudson plugin using Maven.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>hudson-plugin-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version><!-- which version of Hudson is this plugin built against? -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.my-project</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project-hudson-asap-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
<name>my-project-hudson-asap-plugin</name>
<url>http://www.my-project.com</url>
</project>
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.hudson.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:3.0.1:run (default-cli) on project my-project-hudson-asap-plugin: Version of org.jvnet.hudson.main:gin:jar:2.1.2 is inconsistent with org.jvnet.hudson.main:hudson-war:war:2.2.1 -> [Help 1]
```

I have a feeling it has to do with moving to java 7, it worked in java 6 yet i've made many changes since i moved to java 7.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with different parent version, such as that 2.1.2 mentioned in the error. That should at least change the error message...

Or do you have some specific reason to use 2.2.1 parent, instead of an older one?